# Android file manager with custom bookmarks

Tags: gratis, android, file-management

I have installed Remix OS 3 on my hard drive. It mounts my Windows drive automatically but finding videos is a pain as I have to browse deep down the file system to get to it each time.

The file manager in Remix has Bookmarks but it doesn't look like you can add your own to it.

I am looking for a free Android file manager that allows me to select a path on the mounted drive and save it as a bookmark for easy access.

Answer (score 1):

ES File Explorer can do that, I use it for bookmarking folders on SMB shares

[image]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop

Answer (score 0):

You could try [FX explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx&hl=en&gl=us) (free)

> FX does have a number of unique features over its competitors
>   including its home screen. The home screen of FX is not just your
>   typical `/sdcard` folder but rather is a section of suggested folders (bookmarks),
>   system information available at your fingertips, and a central station
>   for the app to work from. You can see documents, downloads, camera
>   roll, music and `/system` available straight away at launch.

*The idea of the home screen is that you create bookmarks to the folders you actually use, rather than digging through the garbage every app places in the root folder of your SD card.*

[image]

**Other features:**

- Home screen and hierarchical design: FX doesn't just dump you into "/sdcard". The top-level "home screen" shows you local storage, network/cloud storage, media, and bookmarks. The entire app is arranged hierarchically with the home screen at the root.
- "Web Access" lets you manage your phone from a web browser on your local network. This is done entirely between your device and computer--nothing leaves your Wi-Fi. Web access has file management, image and video galleries, and a music player that can stream music to your computer.
- "FX Connect" can transfer files between two devices running FX. Transfers are over Wi-Fi Direct, and connections can be optionally made using NFC by touching two devices together back-to-back.

Comment: Did you get to try out this software? Please advise if it works as you need